# jQuery - Changing dropdownlist index changes also the value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using MVC 4 with Razor engine, I'm creating a dropdownlist doing that :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Genders.GenderId, new SelectList(
    new List<Object> { 
        new { value = 0 , text = "Male"  },
        new { value = 1 , text = "Female" }
    },
    "value",
    "text",
    2), 
    new { id = "ddlGender" })
```

When I'm clicking on a button, I'm getting some info using a Json request and I'm setting the value of the dropdownlist doing like that :

```
if (response.gender == "Male") {
    $("#ddlGender").attr('selectedIndex', 0);
}
else {
    $("#ddlGender").attr('selectedIndex', 1);
}
```

However, when I'm getting a female value, my dropdownlist shows 2 Female values instead of Male and Female value.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use `$("#ddlGender").val('0')` or `$("#ddlGender").val('1')`

Comment: I tried but it modifies my ddl values, not the selected value ...

Comment: No it does not. You must have other code doing that.

Answer (score 2):

this will not work because select tag doesn't have any attribute named selectedIndex.

Your code should be:

```
 $("#ddlGender").get(0).selectedIndex = index_here;
```

or try this

```
$("#ddlGender").val("yourvalue");
```

make sure the value in the options tags is same as "yourvalue".

Comment: Thank you but it still modifies my values... i'm getting female/female when I'm choosing a female.

Comment: @Traffy, Then you have other code modifying the options.

Comment: please create a  fiddle and share the code so that we can assist further if you are still having the same issue.